# Given the index of a matrix, How can I calculate the column of that index?

Tags: assembly, matrix

Say I have a matrix as such:

```
1  0  0  0
0  2  0  6
0  0  3  0
```

and I have the index 11 (which represents the number `3` in the above matrix). I figured out how to find the row of that index: subtract the number of columns in the matrix from the index until its negative or zero, and the number of subtractions is the row. in pseudo-code:

```
numCol = 4
index = 11
temp = index
count = 0
while (temp > 0) {
    temp -= numCol
    count++
}
curRow = count
```

In the case of my example, `index = 11` so `temp` will be subtracted from 3 times so the row is 3

Now how do I get the column?

I'm using ARM assembly with the matrix stored as such:

```
.data
.align
MatA:    .word   2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 6, 0, 0, 3, 0
.end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get the row as you've done, add back in the number of columns, and you're left with the column number.

Comment: well im left with zero or a negative number. So i add the number of columns to that to get back up to the first row, and thats the column?

Comment: Yeah, I was off by one. Either that, or you can stop the first time you're left with the number of columns, or less, then add one to the row count. *Then* you're left with the column number (without adding back in anything).  (I edited my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Division and modulus:

```
row = index / numCol;
col = index % numCol;
```

For your matrix:

```
row = 10 / 4 = 2; (zero indexed)
col = 10 % 4 = 2; (zero indexed)
```

By your repeated subtraction method:

```
numCol = 4;
index = 10;  // (zero-indexed)
temp = index;
count = 0;
while (temp > numCol) {
    temp -= numCol;
    count++;
}
curRow = count;
curCol = temp;
```

Comment: I don't have division and modulus at my disposal

Comment: Why not - aren't you on an ARM?

Comment: To be honest I have no idea. I'm very new to assembly. When I google instructions for ARM assembly the code looks nothing like what I'm using. My school did give me an ARMSim (ARM simulator) program which I'm using..

Comment: ARM definitely has division instructions.  There is lots of documentation at [arm.com](http://arm.com).